# How to combine multiple results from a String object in android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to concat multiple results which is generating separately. Already tried to put the results in a TextView but it only shows thw last result.

```
Log.wtf("Concat ", msg2);

E/Concat: A4 Paper 6  ->   $ 57.0
E/Concat: JetPen 8  ->   $ 105.0
E/Concat: Shopper 9  ->   $ 110.25
E/Concat: Pilot 10  ->   $ 70.0
E/Concat: Valentine Card 2  ->   $ 60.0
```

```
List<Basket> items = ((BasketAdapter)binding.get().basketRecycler.getAdapter()).getItems();

        for(Basket basket : items){
            //Log.wtf("Name ", basket.product.name);
            //Log.wtf("Price ", basket.basketPrice + "");
            //Log.wtf("Count ", basket.count + "");
            float subTotal = basket.basketPrice * basket.count;

            String message = basket.product.name +"  "+"->"+"  "+" $ "+subTotal;
            Log.wtf("Concat ", message);
```

Comment: have you tried about StringBuilder or StringBuffer ?

Comment: @ParthPatel Please can you give me an example, I'm new to this !

Comment: For that, you have to post your actual source code with sample data. So I can guide you in a way

Comment: @ParthPatel Data is dynamic also number of results depends upon the size of recycler items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , your code is not working because you are creating new string every time inside of for loop. What I have done is created a variable message outside for loop and concatinated it inside loop using += operator

```
    List<Basket> items = 
    ((BasketAdapter)binding.get().basketRecycler.getAdapter()).getItems();

    String message = "";

    for(Basket basket : items){
        //Log.wtf("Name ", basket.product.name);
        //Log.wtf("Price ", basket.basketPrice + "");
        //Log.wtf("Count ", basket.count + "");
        float subTotal = basket.basketPrice * basket.count;

        message += basket.product.name +"  "+"->"+"  "+" $ "+subTotal;
        Log.wtf("Concat ", message);
```

Comment: message += basket.product.name +"  "+"->"+"  "+" $ "+subTotal+"\n";

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring String message in for loop. Thats why each time new object is created. Declare String message outside of for loop.